# How can I use a preloaded row in an Ecto WHERE filter?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have an Ecto schema `Preference` that has a `belongs_to` relationship called `home_address` with another schema `Address`. The following query works to retrieve the desired information, but I don't like how I can't preload the association, and instead have to return pairs:

```
    from(p1 in MyApp.Accounts.Preferences.Preference,
      join: p2 in MyApp.Accounts.Preferences.Preference,
      join: a1 in assoc(p1, :home_address),
      join: a2 in assoc(p2, :home_address),
      where:
        p1.owner_id != p2.owner_id and
          st_dwithin(
            st_transform(a1.geom, 3857),
            st_transform(a2.geom, 3857),
            p1.range + p2.range
          ),
      select: [{p1, a1}, {p2, a2}]
    )
```

I would like to do something like this, but:

```
    from(p1 in MyApp.Accounts.Preferences.Preference,
      join: p2 in MyApp.Accounts.Preferences.Preference,
      preload: [home_address: p1, home_address: p2],
      where:
        p1.owner_id != p2.owner_id and
          st_dwithin(
            st_transform(p1.home_address.geom, 3857),
            st_transform(p2.home_address.geom, 3857),
            p1.range + p2.range
          ),
      select: [p1, p2]
    )
```

But, in that case, I receive the following error:

```
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) cannot fetch field `geom` from `p1.home_address`. Can only fetch fields from:

  * sources, such as `p` in `from p in Post`
  * named bindings, such as `as(:post)` in `from Post, as: :post`
  * parent named bindings, such as `parent_as(:post)` in a subquery
```

How can I preload the associations and just return the two desired `Preference` records?

Comment: the answer is written there, you have to use a named binding

Comment: @Daniel I see the error message; I don't see a solution. I'm not sure how to use named bindings to solve this problem. If you do, I would love to approve a posted solution from you.